# Extract specific alphabetic characters using SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, utf-8

*Background:* I am using PostgreSQL 11 on CentOS. I have a database having UTF-8 encoding, in specific tables I have some Latin characters as follows [ÄéÒçòý]

*Objective:* I want to replace those with standard English characters for that I am trying to use the following query to list down those specific characters but getting all characters set  :

```
SELECT name_0 from public.gadm36_0_iso2_iso3 where name_0 ~ '[[:alpha:]]';
```

[image]

I am searching on my side and referring to some [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56029995/test-column-for-special-characters-or-only-characters-numbers) as well.

Any help/any suggestions would be great !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions for this

`SELECT 'ÄéÒçòý' ~* '\A[A-Z0-9]*\Z';`

The output should be false for the above SQL statement. So use this in your where clause.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for `unaccent`:

```
CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;

SELECT unaccent('ÄéÒçòý');

 unaccent 
----------
 AeOcoy
(1 row)
```