# Count specific characters in a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with a list of titles. I am trying to figure out a way of creating a substring query that will let me count the number of times that a particular character occurs in the entire column. Such as, how many times does the letter 'A' occur? I am thinking of the substring since I want to know the count for letters A - I.

I need a new table that shows the substring letters (say A-Z) and next to them the total number of times that letter occurs in the entire column (not just in each row).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting the number of occurrences of a substring within a string in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36376410/counting-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-substring-within-a-string-in-postgresql)

Comment: Somewhat, but that gives the number of times A occurs in each row. I need a new table that lists A-Z as a substring and next to it the number of times that letter occurs in the entire column of the original table.

Answer (score 0):

For the basic **ASCII** letters like A-Z (as mentioned) and a (typical) UTF-8 or LATIN* encoding (or most others):

```
SELECT chr(c) AS letter
     , sum(octet_length(col)
         - octet_length(translate(col, chr(c), ''))) AS total_count
FROM   generate_series (ascii('A'), ascii('Z')) c
CROSS  JOIN tbl
GROUP  BY 1;
```

[`translate()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) works for single-character replacements and is a bit faster than [`replace()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) - which you would use looking for multi-character strings.

In (typical) UTF-8 or LATIN* encoding, basic ASCII letters are represented with a single byte. This allows the faster function [`octet_length()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html). To count characters encoded with more bytes, use [`length()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) instead, which counts characters instead of bytes.

Also, we can conveniently generate a range of letters like A-Z with [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html), because their byte-representation lines up in a continuous range in the mentioned encodings. Convert to `integer` with [`ascii()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) and back with [`chr()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html).

Then `CROSS JOIN` to your table (`tbl`), measure the difference between original length and after removing the letter of interest, and sum.

**But** while counting many of the characters in your strings, this alternative approach is **probably much faster**:

```
SELECT letter, count(*) AS total_count
FROM   tbl, unnest(string_to_array(col, NULL)) letter
WHERE  ascii(letter) BETWEEN ascii('A') AND ascii('Z')
GROUP  BY 1;
```

To count case-insensitive, throw in `lower()` or `upper()`:

```
FROM   tbl, unnest(string_to_array(upper(col), NULL)) letter
```

To check for multiple non-continuous ranges of characters:

```
WHERE  letter ~ '^[a-zA-Z]$'  -- a-z and A-Z separately (case-sensitive)
```

Or a random selection:

```
WHERE  'abcXYZ' ~ letter
```

[`string_to_array()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) with separator `NULL` splits the string into an array of single characters, [`unnest()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) (using implicit `CROSS JOIN LATERAL`), filter the ones of interest (again, using their byte-representation to make it fast. Then simply count per character.

Related:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)
- [PostgreSQL 9.1 using collate in select statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795185/postgresql-9-1-using-collate-in-select-statements/7830135#7830135)

Comment: The code is case sensitive, yes. You did not mention case-insensitive ... I added a solution.

Comment: I apologize for that.

Comment: Thank you so very much for this. I feel so stupid in asking this, but how would it work for both upper and lower at the same time?

Comment: To count them separately, so case-sensitive again? I added some more above.

Comment: To count them as a complete total, all upper and lower e's at the same time, not separately.

Comment: The variant with `upper()` does just that. (That's what case-insensitive means.)